# How to turn on audio on click icon play/pause

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive

I have play/pause icon. I need to turn on audio if I press on it. I created icon, but when press on it nothing happens, I mean something went wrong.

CSS:

```
.player {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    background: url('https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149657.svg') no-repeat center center;
 }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="player">
    <img src="" onclick="togglePlay(this)" id="button">
    <audio>
        <source src="https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mp3/bachfugue.mp3" />
    </audio>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function togglePlay(video) {
  var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
  if (audio) {
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
        document.getElementById("button").src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149658.svg";
    } else {
        audio.pause();
        document.getElementById("button").src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149657.svg";
    }
  }
}
```

What is the problem? I need to have my img on css. How to turn on audio using icon? Help me if you can. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try onclick method on player class. It works.

```
<div class="player" onclick="togglePlay(this)">
    <img src="" id="button">
    <audio>
        <source src="https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mp3/bachfugue.mp3" />
    </audio>
</div>
```

Comment: I got this error: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of null
    at togglePlay`

Comment: Works for me as well. See here: https://codepen.io/stevenkuipers/pen/XGpWMO

Comment: @ravi Yes! it helped, but image does not change to another. Please, help me to solve that

Answer (score 0):

Minor changes required to your code. See code snippet below.

```js
function togglePlay() {
  var audio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
   
  if (audio) {
    if (audio.paused) {
        audio.play();
       document.getElementById("button").src = "https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149658.svg";
    } else {
        audio.pause();
        document.getElementById("button").src ="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149657.svg";
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.player {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="player">
  <img id ="button" onclick="togglePlay()" src ="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149657.svg">
    <audio>
        <source src="https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mp3/bachfugue.mp3" />
    </audio>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to have my img in css, because in html it does not appear.

Comment: yes, I am using svg. but when I write it in html it does not appear on the page

Comment: check your path is correct or not. Here svg shows well. Try 'Run code snippet'.

Answer (score 0):

firstly define two styles for pause and play,

```
.playbg{
  background:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149657.svg);
}

.pausebg{
    background:url(https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/149/149658.svg);
}
```

Then give the player an ID, of "player" for referencing...

```
<div id="player" class="player">
    <img src="" onclick="togglePlay(this)" id="button">
    <audio>
       <source src="https://ccrma.stanford.edu/~jos/mp3/bachfugue.mp3" />
    </audio>
</div>
```

Here we define the scripts, and ensure to load jquery as i did below.. 
when the page loads, `$(document).ready` it initializes the button with a play button, and when

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    //when the page loads, set the paused property to true
    var paused = true;

    //add the play image to the button... 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#player').find('img').addClass('playbg');    
    });

   //and the toggle play button checks and sees if the variable is set or not, and replaces the image background, by alternating the classes using jquery. 

  function togglePlay() {
      var audio = $('#player').find('audio');         
      if (paused) {
            //audio.play();
            $('#player').find('img').removeClass('playbg').addClass('pausebg'); 
            paused = false;
        } else {
            //audio.pause();
            $('#player').find('img').removeClass('playbg').addClass('pausebg');

        }
      }
    }   
</script>
<script type="text/javascript> src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have tried you variant, but I can not see images.

Comment: i utilized the jquery library, add jquery to your project. and i just made a little edit

Comment: but I do not use controls. I just need to use `play/pause` icons. Could you rewrite it using just these icons?

Comment: I tried to use your code withour controls, but it did not help me(

Comment: hello, why not try the code above, my final edit, i hope it works this time.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189513/discussion-between-andaeiii-and-asas-sas).

Comment: I do know what is happening, but it does not work for me. Especially image does not appear. and `playbg`/`pausebg` does not work. I do not know what is the problem..